"routing-controllers" + "express" does dot provide the access on HTTPS protocol at local development mode
Although I have not found the idiomatic code for Express.js + routing-controllers, rely on this hint on the GitHub discussions, I suppose it will be:
import HTTPS from "https";
import Path from "path";
import BodyParser from "body-parser";
import createExpressApplication from "express";
import type { Express as ExpressApplication } from "express";
import { useExpressServer as supportClassSyntax } from "routing-controllers";


const expressApplication: ExpressApplication = createExpressApplication().

    // Use various plugins

    use(BodyParser.json());
    
  
HTTPS.createServer(
  {
    key: FileSystem.readFileSync(
      Path.join(process.cwd(), "ssl" "SSL_Key-FrontServer.LocalDevelopment.pem"), "utf8"
    ),
    cert: FileSystem.readFileSync(
      Path.join(process.cwd(), "ssl", "SSL_Certificate-FrontServer.LocalDevelopment.pem"), "utf8"
    )
  },
  expressApplication
);


supportClassSyntax(
  expressApplication,
  {
    controllers: [
      // ...
    ]
  }
).

    listen(
      443,
      (): void => {
        console.log("Server started")
      }
    );

Please note that I have confirmed that the paths to SSL Certificate and SSL Key are correct because if I intentionally specify the wrong path to SSL Certificate and/or SSL Key, the application will crash with "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory".
If to try to access "https://localhost:443", it will be the "The site can' provide a secure connection" error at browser (my interface has Japanese language, so I have used the side screenshot with same English message, and "domanin.com" on this screenshot is actually "localhost:443" in my case):

However, http://localhost:443/ works.
What is wrong? I don't need the http, I need the https.
The function useExpressServer from "routing-controllers" (I have aliased it as  supportClassSyntax) return the instance of the Express application which has listen method. No errors should be here.
"How you have obtained the SSL certificate and key?"
By the mkcert utility:
mkcert localhost 127.0.0.1

As far I as have understood, the port number does not matters.

In your browser the the fqdn is "domain.com", why did you not include that in you mkcert command? You need a valid certificate for that domain. Also: mkcert does not create a full trusted chain, because they certs that are issued are self singed.

@Marc, Oh, sorry. This screenshot is not mine one because I have the Japanese UI which could not be read by most of SO users. I am opening my app in https://localhost:443.

I believe your main problem is you are calling listen off of the server returned from your aliased useExpressServer which doesn't know about your certificate:
supportClassSyntax(
  expressApplication,
  {
    controllers: [
      // ...
    ]
  }
).listen(443, (): void => { // <--- don't call listen here
  console.log('server started')
})

Instead, you should call listen from your https server while only passing the express application with any configured middleware to useExpressServer.
import HTTPS from "https";
import Path from "path";
import BodyParser from "body-parser";
import createExpressApplication from "express";
import type { Express as ExpressApplication } from "express";
import { useExpressServer as supportClassSyntax } from "routing-controllers";

const expressApplication: ExpressApplication = createExpressApplication()
const httpsServer = HTTPS.createServer(
  {
    key: FileSystem.readFileSync(
      Path.join(process.cwd(), "ssl" "SSL_Key-FrontServer.LocalDevelopment.pem"), "utf8"
    ),
    cert: FileSystem.readFileSync(
      Path.join(process.cwd(), "ssl", "SSL_Certificate-FrontServer.LocalDevelopment.pem"), "utf8"
    )
  },
  expressApplication
);

expressApplication.use(BodyParser.json());

supportClassSyntax(
  expressApplication,
  {
    controllers: [
      // ...
    ]
  }
)

// Now call listen from your HTTPS server with the configured certificate
httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
  console.log("server started")
});


Thank you for the answer! You are completely right. Accept & upvote & prize.
